# Ruby Net:HTTP ensure get *finishes* within a time

Tags: ruby, timeout, net-http

I am trying to use `Net:HTTP` to pull in a file remotely.

I know (and have set) both `read_timeout` and `open_timeout` , however, those just set that the handshake has been completed within a time, and that the read has started receiving data. However, I want to ensure that the image is downloaded within 1 second (say) or aborts.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

url = URI.parse "http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/74000/74393/world.topo.200407.3x21600x10800.png"

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = url.scheme == "https"

http.read_timeout = 1
http.open_timeout = 1
resp = http.start() {|http|
  http.get(url.path)
}
```

Now, this succeeds, but it certainly isn't downloading the 110meg image within 1 second (not on my connection anyway).

According to this [well cited article by Mike Perham](http://www.mikeperham.com/2015/05/08/timeout-rubys-most-dangerous-api/) timeout is evil, so, what *is* the right way to timeout a `Net:HTTP` call?

To be clear, the code above *will not complete* within 1 second, and I want to know the correct way to abort a get request (as I don't want it sitting around forever tying up a ruby process)